# py.game.mixer.music unable to load .wav files (results in crashed kernel)

Tags: python-3.x, pygame, crash, spyder, mixer

I am trying to play a .wav file with the `pygame` module, however, whenever I run the code block below, it crashes the kernel after a short period of time.

```
from pygame import mixer

mixer.init()

fname = "journey.wav"
s = mixer.music.load(fname)
```

The message:

[image: The message]

I'm pretty sure this issue is unique to me, but I don't exactly know what is causing it. 
Thank you for your time.

Comment: No problem running the code here.

Comment: that's strange...

Comment: You're using a very old version of Spyder (almost two years old, I'd say). Please update to Spyder 3.3.6 at least, that should fix your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem before. But after deep searching on the web I figured out that pygame doesn't support 32-bit float WAVs. Re-encode it to a signed 16-bit WAV. Here's [how to do that](https://learn.adafruit.com/microcontroller-compatible-audio-file-conversion) using audacity.

Hope it helps you :)